# NetSuite Suitelet/RESTlet to display VueJS app

Tags: vue.js, netsuite

I am attempting to build a popup Suitlete that displays a Vue app. It needs to have the ability to pass data back and forth into the transaction that opened it.

Has anyone done this in the past and if so what did the setup for the Vue files and the Suitelet/RESTlet look like? Can't seem to find examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can find projects on GitHub that have great Vue/NetSuite project file setups, ones where you can use Vue CLI to work locally that still work with RESTlets. Here's one https://github.com/michoelchaikin/netsuite-mapreduce-util